# Android app Register with SQL

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm currently making a quiz app, and I want to add a feature where users can register, and then use SQL to store this. I have followed this YouTube tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NT1qxmqH1eM

However, when I have register a new user and try to login with this, it says "invalid password". So the data isn't being stored...

**Home.java**

Looks like this:

[image]

The code for **Home.java** is:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Button btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
    Button btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentSignIN = new Intent(Home.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignIN);
        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentSignUP = new Intent(Home.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Pressing the SIGN UP button takes you to **Register.java** which looks like this:

[image]

The code for **Register.java** is:

```
public class Register extends Activity {

LoginDataBaseAdapter helper = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

}

public void onRegisterClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.register_complete) //changed from xml in activity_home which has id buttonSignUP
    {
        EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        EditText pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        EditText pass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);

        String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
        String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
        String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();

        if (!pass1str.equals(pass2str))
        {
            //popup message
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }
        else
        {
            //insert input in database
            UserInfo u = new UserInfo();
            u.setEmail(emailstr);
            u.setPass(pass1str);

            helper.insertUserInfo(u);
        }
        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Register.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(registerIntent);
    }
}
}
```

I'm able to enter the details, click "complete registration" which then takes me back to Home.java. However, when I try to log in with a newly registered user, it's says that password is unknown. I guess it means the register data isn't then properly stored, but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

**LoginActivity.java**

I have used the template provided by Android Studio so most of this code isn't written by me. However, I have commented the code that I have added to it in order to create this database:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {



LoginDataBaseAdapter helper = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);             //FOR THE REGISTER DATABASE

/**
 * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
 */
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

/**
 * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
 * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
 */



private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
        "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
};

private User myUser;


/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);


}

public void onRegisterClick(View v){                //FOR THE REGISTER DATABASE (this method)
        EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        String str = a.getText().toString();
        EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        String pass = b.getText().toString();

        String password = helper.searchPass(str);

        if (pass.equals(password)){
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Play.class);
            i.putExtra("Username", str);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else {
            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and password don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            temp.show();
        }
    }


private void populateAutoComplete() {
    if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
        return;
    }

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    return false;
}


/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            populateAutoComplete();
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
private void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return email.contains("@");
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return password.length() > 4;
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            // Select only email addresses.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                    " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
            .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

            // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
            // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

}

private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
    //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

    mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
    };

    int ADDRESS = 0;
    int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DBTools dbTools=null;
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return false; //changed
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {                                                                  ///if successful login
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
              mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
}
```

**LoginDataBaseAdapter.java**

```
public class LoginDataBaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userinfo.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "userinfo";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table userinfo (email text not null, pass text not null);";


public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.db = db;


}

public void insertUserInfo(UserInfo u) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, u.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, u.getPass());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public String searchPass(String email) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select email, pass from " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String a, b;
    b = "not found";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
            a = cursor.getString(0);
            b = cursor.getString(1);

            if(a.equals(email)) {
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return b;
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    this.onCreate(db);

}
}
```

**UserInfo.java**

```
public class UserInfo {

String email, pass;

public void  setEmail(String email)
{
    this.email = email;
}
public String getEmail()
{
    return this.email;
}

public void setPass(String pass)
{
    this.pass = pass;
}
public String getPass()
{
    return this.pass;
}
}
```

I'm new to programming, and I'm doing this for a school project, so a detailed explanation would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a specfic answer for your issue but one thing that would help is to check the SQLite database for the username and password after inserting the values. By checking the the values on the database you can see if the values that were recorded for the username. One easy way of checking the database is by using [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) which enables chrome developer tools, among them the ability to see the database.

To add stetho to your app, just add `compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'` to your dependencies in the app gradle file.

[image]

[image]

And once the app loads g`chrome://inspect/#devices` to show the devices and then select your app.

[image]

After that you can see the contents of the database
[image]